# Holomorphicity of Function $\int_\alpha \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta - z} \, d \zeta $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

This was from Freitag's p247.

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic (holomorphic)
>   function. $\phi:D \times D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by   $ \phi
>  (\zeta,z) = \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta - z}$ if $\zeta \not= z$ and
>   $\phi(z,z) = f'(z)$ if $\zeta = z$. *We have shown that this function is analytic.*
>
> **Lemma B.3(p247):** $G: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $G(z) = \int_\alpha \phi(\zeta, z) \, d\zeta$ is analytic in $D$ by the Leibniz rule.

My problem is the second statement about analyticity of $G$. For us to apply [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), we need $\alpha$ to be smooth (?) so we can write the integral as $\int_a^b \phi(\alpha(t),z) \alpha'(t) \, dt $. But $\alpha$ is an arbitrary closed curve here.

Comment: Complex line integrals are defined for piecewise-smooth paths, so I think you can apply the Leibniz rule just well?

Comment: $\alpha$ here is any arbitrary closed curve?

Comment: Then, how is the complex integral along $\alpha$ defined?

Comment: I use the definition similar to https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/246a-notes-2-complex-integration/ , but yes, thanks a lot, any closed curve in an open set is homotopic to a polygonal path, so we can work on a piecewise smooth path (?)